# Get HTTP response code on non-2xx apiFetch request

Tags: javascript, rest-api

I'm using WordPress' apiFetch library to make requests (in WordPress admin dashboard) to my WordPress REST endpoints. It looks like apiFetch will throw an error if the response is a non-2xx code, using the JSON body of the response as the error. However, it does not appear to be inserting the HTTP code anywhere in that error.

This is necessary since it allows me to differentiate between a "normal" error (like 404 if the resource asked for does not exist) and an "unexpected" error (like a 500 internal server error).

Comment: It looks like it's still expecting a JSON response body in a failure case, which is what it returns instead. Maybe your API could return JSON in the normal error cases too? But I agree swallowing the status code is not useful.

Comment: I'm catching all errors in the PHP endpoint and returning a JSON-formatted generic "Internal server error" message, so even unexpected errors would still be JSON. I could just check for the presence of an error key in the JSON object, but I'm trying to indicate the type of error as much as possible by HTTP codes rather than some sort of unique error string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default, apiFetch will parse the response for you automatically. You can get the raw response object by setting `parse` to `false` in the `apiFetch` option, e.g.:

```js
const handleClick = async () => {
    try {
        const result = await apiFetch( {
            path: '/your/path',
            parse: false,
        } );
        console.log( result ) // you will see ok status (e.g. 200) in here.
    } catch ( error ) {
        console.log( error ); // you will see error status (e.g. 404 or 500) in here.
    }
};
```

More info: [apiFetch's parse option](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/c19bd61f46cead687f9627777aaa720f13832acf/packages/api-fetch/README.md#parse-boolean-default-true)

Relevant code for parsing the response: see [utils/response.js in apiFetch](https://github.com/WordPress/gutenberg/blob/c19bd61f46cead687f9627777aaa720f13832acf/packages/api-fetch/src/utils/response.js#L14-L24)